# Can I use the $map aggregation framework operator in ReactiveMongo aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, scala, aggregation-framework, reactivemongo

I would like to implement the following aggregation pipeline using Scala Reactive Mongo:

```
aggregate([
  { "$match": {"_id": ObjectId("5f22aca9b99533f2092b590c")}},
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "teams": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$teams",
          "as": "team",
          "cond": {
            "$anyElementTrue": {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$$team.metadata",
                "in": { 
                  "$or": [
                    {"$eq": ["$$this.status.active", true]},
                    {"$eq": ["$$this.scores.active", true]}
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }               
        }                 
      }
    }
  }

])
```

But I can't seem to find any documentation regarding the `$map` operation in Reactive mongo.
My questions are:

1. Is it possible to do this in Reactive Mongo?
2. Is there another way to implement the same pipeline using other stages that are supported in Reactive Mongo?

Comment: `$map` is not an aggregation stage, but an operator used within stage (such as `$project`): https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/